# Selenium / ChromeDriver - Clicking in the center of an element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

So I ran into a new issue today that I have not experienced for, and it relates to the nature of the Chrome Driver (I believe Chrome is the only one that does this..). I am aware that when you click an element using .click() it clicks in the center. However this is troubling because I am trying to click a checkbox that just so happens to have a link nested in the center. 
[image]

I have tried using the JavaScript Executor as well and no luck.. Does anyone know a way around this? Yes I have tried just accessing the box but it doesnt have an identifier I can use..

[image]

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: @guy alright, I added it.

Comment: It doesn't show the check box html. It should be above the `<label>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't add here the check box html I will assume it is something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id">
<label for="checkbox_id">Something</label>
```

So you just have to click the input and not the label. It will look like this:

```
driver.findElemnt(By.id("checkbox_id")).click();
```

Or using xPath:

```
 driver.findElemnt(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can click using coordinates

> Coordinates co = element.getCoordinates();

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be resolved by two methods

**Method 1:** Find correct xpath of checkboxx use default click

driver.findElement(By.xpath("CheckBoxXPath").click();

**Method 2:** If you really want to click on centre of WebElement then you Actions class method click(WebElement target) this method click on mid of WebElement.
Refer [How to use Actions class clcik method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180016/10385429)