# *Problems finding specific element on page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver

I know there are existing questions on this topic, but none of them seems to help me with this:

I've got a lightbox with several elements.
I can find and access all of these elements, except ONE, using the XPath.

**These are the items:**
Text header: No problem
Text: No problem
Input field: No problem
Text: No problem
Text: No problem
Button (upload file): THIS IS SEEMINGLY IMPOSSIBLE FOR Selenium TO FIND
Button (cancel): No problem
Button (send): No problem

The XPaths for all the elements:

```
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[1]    /content-placeholder/h1
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/ul[1]/li[1]/label/span
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/input
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/label
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/span
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/input
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[5]/content-placeholder/button[1]
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[5]/content-placeholder/button[2]
```

The problematic element is this:

```
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/input
```

As far as I can see, there's no reason why it should be different from the other elements (textfield, button, text)?

I'm accessing all these elements with an implicit wait, to check that they've all loaded before continuing.

```
GCDriver.WaitForVisible("//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/input");
```

From the GCDriver (Selenium Driver) class:

```
public static void WaitForVisible (string xpath) {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(GCDriver.Instance,  
                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(driver => 
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Displayed);
}
```

Now, as mentioned, this works for all the other elements, as well as accessing them directly. For this, the wait times out with WebDriverTimeoutEsception:

```
Result Message: 
Test method Tests.Regression_tests.VerifyOverlays.Verify_Update_Ticket_OverlayContent threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds
```

Also, of course, trying to ACCESS the button with .Click() also fails:

```
GCDriver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/input")).Click();

Result Message: 
Test method Tests.Regression_tests.VerifyOverlays.Verify_Update_Ticket_OverlayContent threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (-208, 307)
```

Here's the html code for the element:

```
<a class="btn btn-grey file-input-container btn-small" data-bind="enable: !uploading() "
   style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 7px 12px; "data-tooltipped=""
   aria-describedby="tippy-tooltip-32" 
   data-original-title="Add Attachment">
   <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"/>
   <span class="mq-for-small-hide">
      <span localize-me="">Add Attachment</span>
   </span>
   <input data-bind="upload: addAttachments, 
    enable: !uploading()" type="file"/>
</a>
```

I've tried some other ways of getting the element, but since this is quite (imo) "messy" html, with no unique ID's or good class names, I've been unable to figure out how.

And it REALLY bugs me that I cannot find it by the XPath. There are 8 elements on the page, all visible and accessible, but this ONE element is impossible to find with Selenium.

The element is there; I can manually click the button on the page while Selenium runs it.

UPDATE:
I also tried using .Enabled instead of .Displayed. Same result.

**UPDATE 2:**
There are two answers below, and I have to select one as the "winner".

*Shubham Jain* gives an answer that, while not the exact thing I was trying to to, is a very good work-around. By using JavaScriptExecutor to try clicking the button, it also checks if the button is visible. However, the answer given doesn't do what it tries to do; Clicking doesn't work quite that way. See **Solution** below to see the correct/working code to click a button using JavaScriptExectutor.

*smit9234*'s answer is exactly what I'm trying to do, although clicking doesn't work that way. To click the button, JS is necessary in this case. However, the question was how to check .Displayed, and that works with the modified XPath he gave me from the code excerpt.

**Solution**

The XPath of the element (button) is, according to FirePath:

```
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/input
```

This, however, doesn't work. Selenium simply cannot find it, even though it's clearly there.

THIS XPath, however, does work:

```
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/span/span
```

However, it works with reagards to the .Displayed check. It does NOT work with Click(). To be able to click the button, I began with Shubham Jain's code example and created this method in the Driver class, to be able to use JavaScript (with Selenium's JavaScriptExecutor) to click the button:

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

 public static void JSClick (string xpath) {
        IWebElement icon = Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
        Actions ob = new Actions(Instance);
        ob.Click(icon);
        IAction action = ob.Build();
        action.Perform();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? .. is there any frame present.

Comment: The error is WebDriverTimeoutException when using the Wait function, and System.InvalidOperationException when trying to click it. All the elements are in an lightbow ("floating" frame) - that hasn't affected anything else than this.

Comment: have you tried fluent or explict wait

Comment: Well. The Wait timout for the .Displayed is 10 seconds. I've tried inserting an explicit Wait before that, but all that accomplishes is that it takes 20 seconds instead of 10 to _not_ find the element.

Comment: so use explicit Wait with 20 sec. is that a problem?

Comment: Well, as I said, it doesn't help. All it accomplishes is that it takes longer for the element to _not_ be found. The element is never found, no matter how long I wait. But it IS there, and I can even click it manually while Selenium runs on the page.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm testing an internal site, and the external version requires a business/customer account to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the html snippet you posted, it seems like this is a file attachment function. Based on the html structure of the snippet, try using the following xpath:

```
.//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a/span/span
```

You should then be able to use the click(); method to click the "Add Attachments"

I assume that clicking on the input doesn't do anything, however you should be able to use the sendKeys(); method for sending the "file path" to the input element.

Comment: That actually worked, with regards to checking the visibility of the button. I double-checked it by getting the element text. However, it's not clickable that way, as suggested by others above. Sending Click() results in this error: System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: Element <span localize-me="">...</span> is not clickable at point (111,306). Other element would receive the click: <input type="file" data-bind="upload:addAttachments,enable: !uploading()">

Answer (score 1):

Use below XPath :-

```
//input[@type='file' and contains(@data-bind,'upload: addAttachments')]
```

You can use `javascriptexecutor`of selenium to click on button. It operated directly on JS of page.

In java :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I don't know more about c# but I believe it something like

```
IWebElement clicks = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", clicks);
```

Change the locator in above elements as per your convenience.

Below you will find more details of javascriptexecutor

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the result is the same: WebDriverTimeoutException.

Comment: When I use the JavaScriptExecutor to click on the button (located with XPath), it returns without errors. However, there is not click performed?

Comment: Yup. It's kind of hard not to be sure about that after messing around with this for 8 hours. I've double- and triple checked so many times that it's ridiculous. Besides, it's a matter of click, copy and paste from Firefox's Firebug->Firepath plugin. But, as I said, using JavaScriptExecutor seems to work, but I'm unable to actually click it that way. It returns with no errors, ovbiously finding the butting, but it's not actually clicked with the above code.

Comment: There is one more way to click using Actions class .. but JavaScriptExecutor should work ....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179670/actions-class-clickwebelement-ele-function-does-not-clicks

Comment: You're right. Clicking didn't quite work with your example, but when building the Actions correctly it works like a charm. I've updated my question with the details of the answer/solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be input element is not visible on the page. you may not use displayed function for that element and try with enabled as given below.

```
public static void WaitForEnabled (string xpath) {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(GCDriver.Instance,  
                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(driver => 
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)).Enabled);
}
```

if the above is not working, you try to click on anchor tag instead of input.

Comment: Incredibly enough, the exact thing happens: It cannot determine the state, and times out just like when using .Displayed.

Comment: you can check with the xpath .//*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a

Comment: try with //*[@id='overlays']/overlay--master/div/div/overlay-lightbox/div/div[3]/content-placeholder/a

Comment: That's not a valid XPath expression either.

Comment: i copied from your question only and validated it using firepath.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not clickable. It looks like there's some javascript on the page with a function called "uploading()".

since you're button has this on it

```
  enable: !uploading()
```

just a test to verify if this is actually the cause, put a breakpoint before your click. on the browser dev tools stick a breakpoint in the uploading() function on the javascript file and see what it's returning.

If this is the case you'll have to use the javascript executor to bypass this.

Comment: The strange thing is that with the JavaScriptExecutor I get no error if I try to click it. But the button is not clicked. I can tak over manually while Selenium is controlling the browser, and the button is most definetely clickable. But not for Selenium, with or without JavaScriptExecutor.

Comment: I think that's because the page's js is hijacking the click event from the browser. The javascript executor directly injects the javascript code and running it in the browser's javascript thread instead of the regular browser thread. I'm not positive on this though so if anyone more knowledgeable sees this please tell us why this works.